# Show "Loading" image while WebView loads page in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

my android app is simple client for web site. It opens site's url, using JavaScript and DOM enters username and password (predefined) and clicks "Log in" button. It uses WebView class.

Question: how during that process I could show some "ajax" loading image  instead of showing webweiv on the same activity?

THank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `WebViewClient` to your webview and use the callbacks `onPagestart` and `onPageFinished` to show the progress.

Comment: thank you! I implemented it by overriding onPageStart and onPageFinished and  ProgressDialog.show